# Why does Intellij IDEA shows require undefined with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

Does anyone know why intellij IDEA underlines require? How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html ?
Same thing happens with default jslint. We put /*jslint node: true */ in the top of the file.

Comment: /*jslint...*/ doesn't help.

Comment: Do you actually have the NodeJS plugin from the plugin repository installed?

Comment: @yole, yes i use nodejs plugin

Comment: found the solution, check my answer :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open preferences page and select `Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries` and select `Node.js Globals`, just like the image below.

No need to add Node.js core modules (I didn't add and worked the same way)

[image: in this screen, select Node.js Globals]

Comment: just edited my answer with the solution, tested here and it worked :)

Comment: The rules say I shouldn't put just a one word comment, so I'm writting this sentence just because I've been trying to get this to work for ages and I just wanted to say: Great!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem on windows, with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3. The solution was:

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Nodejs and NPM:
Click "Enable" button next to Node.js Core library, accept defaults.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why my version isn't quite the same (new version? Fresh install?) but my IntelliJ Ultimate didn't have the Node.js Core library @SergioFilhow mentioned.

I had to go to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM`: "Coding assistance for Node.js". After I configured this for my projects, the Node.js Core library showed up under `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`.