# IntelliJ IDEA - nodejs plugin - passport.initialize() not resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I met an issue that some of the nodeJS module functions are not resolved but others are fine. Here is my step to reproduce this issue:

1. Create a project, choose **NodeJS and NPM**.
2. Choose next, the [project detail snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKLJl.png) is attached and click finish.
3. In app.js, add the following line after app being declared:

   var passport = require('passport');
   app.use(passport.initialize());
4. You should see the initialized() has underscore indicating "Unresolved function or method initialized".

I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4.

I've read the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648517/why-does-intellij-idea-shows-require-undefined-with-nodejs), but it's not fit in my scenario.
Please be noted that only [passport module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/399ay.png) have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, please follow [WEB-18469](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18469) for updates.

As a workaround, please, try downloading passport TypeScript community stubs: `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, press `Download...`, choose **passport** from the list

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way than manually IDE configuration I think, just add passport tying to your dependency.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/passport

```
npm install --save @types/passport
```